# How to disable overflow in Blazor only in certain pages

Tags: css, blazor, overflow

I am building a Blazor server app starting from the Visual Studio template.

I need to disable overflow scroll bars only for one page.
Adding `html, body { overflow : hidden; }` in the relative Blazor component's css it does not work.

The project has already a site.css, if I add the `overflow : hidden;` in there it works but, of course, it will disable it for the whole site.

Comment: Just add an outer  `<div>` to your page. Set the styles on that.

Comment: I just tried ```<div style="overflow : hidden;">``` after all the @inject etc., it does not work. It does not seem to propagate to the body (which makes sense since <body> is above <div>)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can probably apply it to the Layout.  It all depends on whether you're doing anything out of the ordinary in the hosted cshtml page.

Create a copy of the existing Layout and apply the style to the top `page` element.

Modify the `page` element in the css file.

```css
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here's my test page - my new Layout is BaseLayout.razor:

```
@layout BaseLayout
@page "/"

<div style="width:3000px" class="bg-black text-white">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

@code {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cascade your Layout and set the class from any descendent.  This is a simplified version-- in reality, you'd want to more carefully control how you set the class variable-- but you can get the basic idea.  Note that `@body` isn't the html body, it's the Blazor content.

**MainLayout.razor**

```
<div class="@LayoutClass">
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
       @body
    </CascadingValue>
</div>

@code{
    public string LayoutClass = "layout-default";
}
```

**AnyChild.razor**

```
@code{
  [CascadingParameter]
  public MainLayout? Main { get; set; }

  void ChangeRootClass(){
     if (Main is not null) Main.LayoutClass = "AlternatePageClass";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem with minor changes to the template I suggest making scrollbars off by default.

In `MainLayout.razor.css` add the following line to `.page`

```
.page {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `<article />` element needs to be fixed in size. The template uses a `.top-row` that has uses `height: 3.5rem;`

In the same file below `main` add:

```
article {
    height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
}
```

At this stage the scroll bars are off by default and the `<article/>` element occupies the remainder of the screen.

To make a page scroll is easy, just wrap the content in a div:

```
<div class="h-100 overflow-auto">
    ...
</div>
```